# と indicating a condition that results in an inevitable outcome

Tags: particle-と

The japanichiban.com has a list of all Japanese particles and one of the uses of the と-particle is "to indicate a condition that results in an inevitable outcome".

Can someone give an example sentence of this use, please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: how about you ask them?

Comment: 「食べすぎる**と**太るよ。」「急がない**と**遅刻するよ。」とかですかね・・

Comment: This question may be too open-ended for our site. You can try searching on these [sites listed under Bilingual Example Dictionaries on our resource page](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/761/542). Alternatively, you can try using [HiNative](https://hinative.com/en-US) and ask for example sentences directly.

Answer (score 2):

How about...

> [食]{た}べ[過]{す}ぎる**と**[太]{ふと}りますよ。
>   If you eat too much, you will gain weight.
>
> [急]{いそ}がない**と**[遅刻]{ちこく}しますよ。
>   Hurry up, or you'll be late. (Lit. If you don't hurry you'll be late.)
>
> [歩]{ある}きながらスマホ(を)いじる**と**[危]{あぶ}ないよ。
>   Texting while walking is dangerous.
>
> [再冷凍]{さいれいとう}する**と**、[風味]{ふうみ}が[落]{お}ちます。
>   Flavor will be lost if refrozen.
>
> [魚]{さかな}を[食]{た}べる**と**[頭]{あたま}が[良]{よ}くなる。
>   Eating fish makes you smart.
>
> [２]{ふた}つ[買]{か}う**と**[３]{みっ}つ[目]{め}は[無料]{むりょう}
>   Buy 2 get 1 free

Comment: "Can someone give **an example sentence** " >> １つでよかったですかね…？

Comment: "**Can** someone give an example sentence "「はい」か「いいえ」だけで答えてもいいですね ww